# How to set the lower and upper index on summation?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

I have some critical problem writting series in compact notation, the problem is

Whenever I write the series in compact notation like

```
$\sum_{j=1}^{j=10}2^j$
```

The above series in enclosed just in two dollar sign, then summation looks like[image]

When I enclose it in four dollars signs two before and two after the summation signs, then upper and lower indices just appear above and below, but then it comes to the center of new line, which I do not want. How to get the upper and lower  indices just above the summation, instead of eclosing in four dollars signs getting it in center of newline.

Comment: That code does not give that image. Please provide a full minimal example instead of a sniplet like this can we cannot use for anything.

Comment: Additionally the `bibtex` tag is not relevant for your question'

Comment: @daleif Yes sir you are correct the code does not give the image i shared. I was just sharing sample, that it do like that image

Comment: Then what exactly is your question? As already mentioned, we need you to provide relevant code if you want any help. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: @daleif I think you have understood the problem, what does I mean? So, please provide the possible direction towards solution, if you can!

Comment: @daleif when I enclosed the summation in four dollar signs two before and two after, then indices appear just exactly above and below, or use math enviroment writing it in \[sum_{j=1}^{10}2^j\] but the problem is it appear on newline in pdf. How to get this on the same line with indices exactly above and below on the summation?

Comment: As long as you do not provide any (complete) code that shows your problem we cannot help you.

Comment: @daleif But I can not edit the question now, to share the full code with packages sir!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110123/discussion-between-noor-aslam-and-daleif).

Comment: you can use `$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{j=10}2^j$`, but inside a line that is not good style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\limits`: `$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{j=10}2^j$`.

Comment: That is actually not relevant in this case. The user had errors in their document and thus the choices LaTeX made to finish the compilation was wrong

Answer (score 2):

From the chat we can see that the OP had an error in their code. **One should never ignore errors in LaTeX**

In most LaTeX editors LaTeX runs in a mode where it always finish. In this case if there is an error then LaTeX will attempt to make a good guess and move on. These guesses are of course not always right. In the end one can therefore end up with a PDF file where things are not formatted correctly. This is what happend in this case.

Again: never ignore compilation errors.